# Set DIV to draggable only after animation

Tags: jquery-animate, jquery-ui-draggable

Again running into problems:

I would like my #deck DIV to be draggable AFTER it animates, and of course not at all before. I understand now the code does not follow the instructions order as my DIV is draggable straight away even though I placed it after the whole animate function. How do I force it to be draggable only after it reaches its position?

```
$(function (){
  $('#deck').click(function (){
    var slotPos = $('#slot1').position();
    var hand = $("#hand").position(); 
    $(this).animate({
      left: 10+hand.left+slotPos.left,
      top:10 + hand.top}, 400);
    slot1 = true; 
  });
  $('#deck').draggable();
});
```

Any reason why this would not work?

http://jsbin.com/ejeweb/5/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Animate` function is asynchronous. You need to create your draggable object in the callback.

**UPDATE : I have fixed some CSS problems. http://jsbin.com/ugicuy/1/**

```
$(function (){
  $('#deck').click(function (){
    var slotPos = $('#slot1').position();
    var hand = $("#hand").position(); 
    var self = this;

    $(this).animate({
      left: 10+hand.left+slotPos.left,
      top:10 + hand.top}, 400,function(){
         if($(self).hasClass('ui-draggable') === false)
            $(self).draggable();
      });
    slot1 = true; 
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks but unfortunately this does not work. Any idea why? Also, would you mind explaining the `var self = this` line? Why not calling `$(this)` straight away?

Comment: Code updated, you had some CSS problem, z-index among others things